# How to catch the moment when a window starts deminiaturizing?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

`NSWindowDelegate` protocol has a `windowDidDeminiaturize` callback, but no `windowWillDeminiaturize` callback. I need to catch the moment when the window is starting to deminiaturize and make changes to it before the user sees the changes applied.

I can't do the changes in `windowDidMiniaturize` because I need to show another window; if I do it in `windowDidMiniaturize`, this other window will appear as soon as the first one has miniaturized.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm leaving this answer here, but it totally does not work reliably, see my comment below.

You could subclass NSWindow and override `deminiaturize:`.

```
@interface MyWindow : NSWindow
@end

@implementation MyWindow

- (void) deminiaturize:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"window about to deminiaturize!" );
    [super deminiaturize:sender];
}
@end
```

Probably you want the window delegate to take some action when this happens, not the window, so you could do something like this:

```
- (void) deminiaturize:(id)sender
{
    id<NSWindowDelegate> delegate = [self delegate];
    if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(windowWillDeminiaturize)] ) {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(windowWillDeminiaturize)];
    }

    [super deminiaturize:sender];
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, but, unfortunately, my `NSWindow` subclass doesn't intercept `deminiaturize:`, the method just doesn't execute. `miniaturize:` is fine though. Can you please try doing that to see if that's a bug on my side or in the framework?

Comment: Bah, you're right, this totally doesn't work reliably.  It did appear to work earlier when I tried it, but now I see that NSWindow's deminiaturize: IS called if you click the app's icon in the Dock (or if you have "Minimize windows into application icon" set in System Preferences), but it totally does not get called if you just click the minimized window icon in the dock.  Sorry...

Comment: That's what happened to me too, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't, thanks so much anyways